# Плавное движение объекта по диагонали с разными высотой и шириной JS canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

При клике создаётся объект, после движется к координатам клика. Необходимо сделать плавное движение по диагонали. Сейчас может произойти такая ситуация, что сначала объект дойдёт до конца по Y, а потом идёт по X.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var bullets = [];

function Bullet(x, y, r, endX, endY) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;
  this.endX = endX;
  this.endY = endY;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();

    if (this.x + 5 < this.endX) {

      this.x += 5;
    } else {
      this.x -= 5;
    }
    if (this.y + 5 < this.endY) {
      this.y += 5;
    } else {
      this.y -= 5;
    }
  }
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.arc(800, 350, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fill();

  for (let bullet of bullets) {
    bullet.draw();
  }
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  bullets.push(new Bullet(800, 350, 10, e.pageX, e.pageY));
}

animate();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var bullets = [];

function Bullet(x, y, r, endX, endY) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;
  this.endX = endX;
  this.endY = endY;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    
    if (this.x != this.endX || this.y != this.endY) {
      var dx = this.endX - this.x;
      var dy = this.endY - this.y;
      var d = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
      if (d <= 5) {
        this.x = this.endX;
        this.y = this.endY;
      } else {
        this.x += 5 * dx / d;
        this.y += 5 * dy / d;
      }
    }
  }
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.arc(800, 350, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fill();

  for (let bullet of bullets) {
    bullet.draw();
  }
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  bullets.push(new Bullet(0, 0, 5, e.pageX, e.pageY));
}

animate();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: только надо считать смещения не каждый кадр а при создании пульки

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Да. Пусть ТС этим займется.

Comment: ну и конечно в идеале использовать время